# onDraw is called, but nothing is being drawn

Tags: android, ondraw

Nothing is being drawn, even tho function is called.

I tried:
1. Moving super.onDraw(canvas) to beginning and end of onDraw
2. Replacing it with draw(canvas)
3. Creating my view dynamically and statically (I mean, in XML)
4. Adding setWillNotDraw(false)

```
class GameView(context: Context) : View(context) {

    init {
        setWillNotDraw(false) // doesn't change anything
        setBackgroundColor( Color.DKGRAY ) // this actually works, but onDraw is not, why?
    }

    private val ballPaint = Paint(ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG).apply {
        color = 0xfefefe
        style = Paint.Style.FILL
    }

    override fun onDraw(canvas: Canvas?) {
        println("Test") // printed!
        canvas!!.apply {
            drawCircle((width/2).toFloat(), (height/2).toFloat(), 100.0f, ballPaint )
        }
        super.onDraw(canvas)
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: use `color = 0xfffefefe`, not `color = 0xfefefe`

Comment: sure, your welcome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to pskink, that was the problem

```
color = 0xfffefefe.toInt()
```